# Implicitly access variables available from current Process scope but outside current module in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, scope, global-variables

I am creating a platform where users can write a key:value-based config that my application understands. Inside these configs, I provide support to write and call python snippets. Something like below:

```
def func(self, x):
    import MyClass
    return MyClass(x, self.attr1)

attr1 val1
attr2 func(self, x)
attr3 MyClass(x)
```

It can be seen that any value may depend on some other value in the config, for which some object like *self* is made available in the scope. Notice *attr2* v/s *attr3*, both creating an object of the same class but in different scopes.

1. *attr2* evals a python function and passes a reference to *self* to the scope. This function also needs to pass the required information from *self* to *MyClass* constructor.
2. *attr3* directly calls the constructor, but since the object is created in the scope of config object, its reference is available as *parent* to *MyClass* object, and internally it uses *self.parent.attr1* for its creation.

This would end up creating similar objects for my application, i.e. *attr2==attr3*.

From the users' perspective, it can be troublesome when *MyClass* requires many attributes from *self*, and they would need to add all that manually. Secondly, it would be good to provide a homogenous way for such object-creation to users, whether it be via config or python function since both exist under the same outer scope. Hence, I'm looking to provide the following way to define *attr2*, and it should work similarly to *attr3* above:

```
def func(x):
    import MyClass
    return MyClass(x)

attr1 val1
attr2 func(x)
```

Is there any way to implicitly understand such context for application-specific objects, which would be created inside client code?

Comment: I have evaluated and discarded the following approaches as of now: 
 1. Make *self* global. 
 2. User to pass *self* to MyClass. 
 3. Modify the user's code via string manipulation.

Comment: I don't know your usecase, but if the user can use python snippets, why not just provide an API and let the user write a full config script instead of this complicated mix of config and python?

Comment: @Xtrem532 The primary interface for my application is the config. My primary set of the target audience would be naive users, who just know minor python scripting for their own use-cases.

Comment: Providing them with some easy to use config functions and a template file with a big comment `"""YOUR CONFIGURATION HERE"""` would probably work better then this strange python / key-value config mix